# onClick of Image Button the value changes but repeat itself at 10 20 place

Tags: android, listview

I have 6 Image buttons, onclick it changes to and from, but repeats at 10th 20th position. I am clueless, but I am sure it has to do with getView f the adapter. Hence, I am posting my code of the adapter. Help would be appreciated.

```
public class ListAvailibilityAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

     Context context;
     int layoutResourceId;

     protected List<UserAvailibilityModel> listAvailibility;
     LayoutInflater inflater;

     public ListAvailibilityAdapter(Context context, List<UserAvailibilityModel> listAvailibility) {
         this.listAvailibility = listAvailibility;
         this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
         this.context = context;
      }

     public int getCount() {
         if(listAvailibility.size()<=0)
            return 1;
         Log.d("SIZE OF ARRAY-->", String.valueOf(listAvailibility.size()));
         return listAvailibility.size();
     }

     public UserAvailibilityModel getItem(int position) {
         return listAvailibility.get(position);
     }

    /* public List<UserAvailibilityModel> getList(int position) {
         return listAvailibility;
     }*/

     @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return listAvailibility.get(position).getImageMorning();
        }

     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ViewHolder holder;
         View vi = convertView;
         if (convertView == null) {

         holder = new ViewHolder();
         convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_list_availability_item,parent, false);

         holder.txtDate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_date);
         holder.txtDay = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lbl_day);
         holder.imgBtnMorning = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_morning);
         holder.imgBtnAfterNoon = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_afernoon);
         holder.imgBtnEvening = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_evening);

         holder.imgBtnMorningChecked = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_morning_checked);
         holder.imgBtnAfterNoonChecked = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_afernoon_checked);
         holder.imgBtnEveningChecked = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_evening_checked);

         holder.txtMorning = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtMorning);
         holder.txtAfternoon = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtafernoon);
         holder.txtEveing = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtEvening);


         holder.imgBtnMorningChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.imgBtnAfterNoonChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
         holder.imgBtnEveningChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);


         convertView.setTag(holder);
         }

         else {
             holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
             }
         if(listAvailibility.size()<=0)
         {
             holder.txtDate.setText("No Data");
             holder.txtDay.setText("No Data");

         }
         else{

             UserAvailibilityModel userAvailModel = listAvailibility.get(position);
             holder.txtDate.setText(userAvailModel.getDisaplyDate());
             holder.txtDay.setText(userAvailModel.getDisaplyDay());
             holder.imgBtnMorning.setImageResource(userAvailModel.getImageMorning());
             holder.imgBtnAfterNoon.setImageResource(userAvailModel.getImageAfterNoon());
             holder.imgBtnEvening.setImageResource(userAvailModel.getImageEvening());

             final ViewHolder fianlHolder = holder;
             final int finalposition = position;


             fianlHolder.imgBtnMorning.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View convertView) {
                        // if image source equals this drawable then...
                        // else change the image source to this drawable...
                        Toast.makeText( context,"Morning Btn Clicked"+finalposition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  

                        //if(((ImageButton)convertView).getDrawable()==drawableMorning){
                            fianlHolder.imgBtnMorningChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fianlHolder.imgBtnMorningChecked.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
                            getItem(finalposition).setMornigBtnClick(true);
                        //}
                    }
                });



             fianlHolder.imgBtnMorningChecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View convertView) {
                        // if image source equals this drawable then...
                        // else change the image source to this drawable...
                        Toast.makeText( context,"Morning Btn Checked Clicked"+finalposition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        //if(((ImageButton)convertView).getDrawable()==drawableCheck){
                            fianlHolder.imgBtnMorningChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            fianlHolder.imgBtnMorning.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            fianlHolder.imgBtnMorning.setImageResource(R.drawable.morning);
                            getItem(finalposition).setMornigBtnCheckClick(true);
                       // }

                    }
                });




             fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoon.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View convertView) {
                        // if image source equals this drawable then...
                        // else change the image source to this drawable...
                        Toast.makeText( context,"AfterNoon Image Clicked"+finalposition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //if(convertView.getId()==R.id.img_btn_afernoon){
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoonChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoon.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoonChecked.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
                      //  }

                    }
                });

             fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoonChecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View convertView) {
                        // if image source equals this drawable then...
                        // else change the image source to this drawable...
                        Toast.makeText( context,"AfterNoon Btn Checked Clicked"+finalposition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                        //if(convertView.getId()==R.id.img_btn_afernoon_checked){
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoonChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnAfterNoon.setImageResource(R.drawable.afternoon);

                       // }

                    }
                });

             fianlHolder.imgBtnEvening.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View convertView) {
                        // if image source equals this drawable then...
                        // else change the image source to this drawable...
                        Toast.makeText( context,"Evening Image Clicked"+finalposition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        //if(convertView.getId()==R.id.img_btn_evening){
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnEveningChecked.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                           // fianlHolder.imgBtnEvening.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnEveningChecked.setImageResource(R.drawable.check);
                       // }

                    }
                });

             fianlHolder.imgBtnEveningChecked.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View convertView) {
                        // if image source equals this drawable then...
                        // else change the image source to this drawable...
                        Toast.makeText( context,"Eveing Btn Checked Clicked"+finalposition,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  
                       // if(convertView.getId()==R.id.img_btn_evening_checked){
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnEveningChecked.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnEvening.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        fianlHolder.imgBtnEvening.setImageResource(R.drawable.night);
                       // }

                    }
                });



         }

         return convertView;
     }



     private static class ViewHolder {
         TextView txtDate;
         TextView txtDay;
         ImageButton imgBtnMorning;
         ImageButton imgBtnAfterNoon;
         ImageButton imgBtnEvening;
         ImageButton imgBtnMorningChecked;
         ImageButton imgBtnAfterNoonChecked;
         ImageButton imgBtnEveningChecked;
         TextView txtMorning;
         TextView txtAfternoon;
         TextView txtEveing;

         }



}
```

Comment: What is your doubt? You question is a little confused.

Answer (score 0):

I am not clear on your question or problem. But it seems you have peculiar issues with displaying data on ListView correctly. Try this sample code in getView() in one of the onClick():

```
fianlHolder.imgBtnMorning.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View convertView) {
      ...
      ImageButton imgBtn = (ImageButton) convertView;
      imgBtn.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
      ...
      notifyDataSetChanged();
      ...
```

Notes:

- It is safer to use the **View parameter** since that is the view that is in focus/clicked. And I think it looks simpler and generic.
- Typecast the View to the appropriate class type. Otherwise a possible crash.
- Perhaps the most important. The call to `notifyDataSetChanged` forces, normally, to refresh ListView if the data impacted is visible.